# Ag-grid: Need functionality of non connected fields of row should be copied it in single line

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using `ag-grid` enterprise version. Need functionality of non connected field of row should be copied in single line.

[image]

`Ag-grid` copies above selected fields into below format
Aleksey Nemov
Russia
01/10/2000

Instead, I need that be copied in single line
Aleksey Nemov, Russia, 01/10/2000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `sendToClipboard` callback to control the data when copy is used. What you need to do it replace the line breaks with  `,`.

To achieve what you want, you'll need a bespoke API of some sort to interact with the Clipboard to copy what you want. Try the following code.

Add this callback function to your grid:

```
sendToClipboard(params) {
    copy(params.data.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, ', '));
}
```

And use the following `copy` function to add the text to your clipboard:

```
function copy(text) {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('value', text);
    document.body.appendChild(input);
    input.select();
    var result = document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(input);
    return result;
 }
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ENBXnxVpFlgYB8Kf) is a plunker to show you this in action.

Comment: How can we paste same copied content in any text editor?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: sendToClipboad is to control the data when we use copy. Now I'd like to paste the copied content to any text editor(suppose say, notepad). Do I need to use clipboard services once data is modified in sendToClipboard callback?

Comment: above code just logs the data into console with comma separator

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The only answer I see by using execCommand. I was expecting that functionality from ag-grid in any upgraded version